# Hive queries of external tables stored on Google Cloud Storage extremely slow

Tags: google-hadoop

I have begun testing The Google Cloud Storage connector for Hadoop. I am finding it incredibly slow for hive queries run against it.

It seems a single client must scan the entire file system before starting the job, 10s of 1000s of files this takes 10s of minutes. Once the job is actually running it performs well.

Is this a configuration issue or the nature of hive/gcs? Can something be done to improve performance.

Running CDH 5.3.0-1 in GCE

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say it's necessarily a MapReduce vs Hive difference, though there are possible reasons it could be more common to run into this type of slowness using Hive.

It's true that metadata operations like "stat/getFileStatus" have a slower round-trip latency on GCS than local HDFS, on the order of 30-70ms instead of single-digit milliseconds.

However, this doesn't mean it should take >10 of minutes to start a job on 10,000 files. Best-practice is to allow the connector to "batch" requests as much as possible, allowing retrieval of up to 1000 fileInfos in a single round-trip.

The key is that if I have a single directory:

```
gs://foobar/allmydata/foo-0000.txt
....<lots of files following this pattern>...
gs://foobar/allmydata/foo-9998.txt
gs://foobar/allmydata/foo-9999.txt
```

If I have my Hive "location" = `gs://foobar/allmydata` it should actually be very quick, because it will be fetching 1000 files at a time. If I did `hadoop fs -ls gs://foobar/allmydata` it should come back in <5 seconds.

However, if I have lots of small subdirectories:

```
gs://foobar/allmydata/dir-0000/foo-0000.txt
....<lots of files following this pattern>...
gs://foobar/allmydata/dir-9998/foo-9998.txt
gs://foobar/allmydata/dir-9999/foo-9999.txt
```

Then this could go awry. The Hadoop subsystem is a bit naive, so that if you just do `hadoop fs -ls -R gs://foobar/allmydata` in this case, it will indeed first find the 10000 directories of the form `gs://foobar/allmydata/dir-####`, and then run a for-loop over them, one-by-one listing the single file under each directory. This for-loop could easily take > 1000 seconds.

This was why we implemented a hook to intercept at least fully-specified glob expressions, released back in May of last year:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gcp-hadoop-announce/MbWx1KqY2Q4

```
7. Implemented new version of globStatus which initially performs a flat
   listing before performing the recursive glob logic in-memory to
   dramatically speed up globs with lots of directories; the new behavior is
   default, but can disabled by setting fs.gs.glob.flatlist.enable = false.
```

In this case, if the subdirectory layout was present, the user can opt instead to do `hadoop fs -ls gs://foobar/allmydata/dir-*/foo*.txt`. Hadoop lets us override a "globStatus", so by using this glob expression, we can correctly intercept the entire listing without letting Hadoop do its naive for-loop. We then batch it up efficiently, such that we'll retrieve all 10,000 fileInfos again in <5 seconds.

This could be a bit more complicated in the case of Hive if it doesn't allow as free usage of glob expressions.

Worst case, if you can move those files into a flat directory structure then Hive should be able to use that flat directory efficiently.

Here's a related JIRA from a couple years ago describing the similar problem for how Hive deals with files in S3, still officially unresolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-951

If it's unclear how/why the Hive client is performing the slow for-loop, you can add `log4j.logger.com.google=DEBUG` to your `log4j.properties` and re-run the Hive client to see detailed info about what the GCS connector is doing under the hood.